# How to calculate a degenerate hypergeometric function of two variables

Tags: integration

How to calculate a degenerate hypergeometric function of two variables with a form of 
$\Phi(\alpha,\beta,\gamma; x,y )={\Gamma(\gamma)\over \Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\gamma-\alpha)}\int_0^1 u^{\alpha-1}u^{\gamma-\alpha-1}(1-ux)^{-\beta}e^{uy}du$ via matlab. Can we use quadrature? If so, how?

Comment: Don't have Matlab here but:  One of your u^(xxx) is undoubtedly wrong otherwise you could merge them.  An online reference (which only gives references ) is at: http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.25  and http://apps.nrbook.com/bateman/Vol1.pdf   -- But neither is very detailed.   Bateman is quite informative but I am not sure how practical.  Any advice I would give would undoubtedly be misleading.

Comment: I did run across: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.141299  There is a volume two but I can't find it online.